# How do I recursively delete directories with wildcard?

Tags: wildcards, rm, recursive

I am working through SSH on a WD My Book World Edition. Basically I would like to start at a particular directory level, and recursively remove all sub-directories matching `.Apple*`. How would I go about that?

I tried

`rm -rf .Apple*` and `rm -fR .Apple*`

neither deleted directories matching that name within sub-directories.

Comment: Related post - [How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/377438/605028) & [How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/785519/465053)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete directories based on \`find\` output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/how-to-delete-directories-based-on-find-output)

Comment: `sudo find . -type d -name "build" -exec rm -r {} +` Does the trick for me :)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`find` is very useful for selectively performing actions on a whole tree.

```
find . -type f -name ".Apple*" -delete
```

Here, the `-type f` makes sure it's a file,  not a directory, and may not be exactly what you want since it will also skip symlinks, sockets and other things. You can use `! -type d`, which literally means not directories, but then you might also delete character and block devices. I'd suggest looking at the `-type` predicate on the man page for `find`.

To do it strictly with a wildcard, you need advanced shell support. Bash v4 has the [`globstar` option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option), which lets you recursively match subdirectories using `**`. `zsh` and `ksh` also support this pattern. Using that, you can do `rm -rf **/.Apple*`. This is not POSIX-standard, and not very portable, so I would avoid using it in a script, but for a one-time interactive shell action, it's fine.

Comment: I can get `find . -type d -name .Apple*` to work - it lists all the folders. However, it fails when I add `-delete` at the end. It just comes back with the usage summary. It's running on BusyBox v1.1.1. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Make sure to either quote or escape the `*`, otherwise the shell will expand it, and find will not see it. And as I understood the question, you _don't_ want to get the directories, so make sure to include `!` before `-type d` to tell find not to match directories.

Comment: Whoops... I was a bit ambiguous. I _do_ want to delete just the directories. I will try quoting the wildcard name.

Comment: `-delete` is not POSIX either. `**` was introduced by `zsh` in the early 90s. It's now (by chronological order of appearance) also in ksh93, fish, bash and tcsh.

Comment: +1 for `rm -rf **/.Apple*`

Comment: @codedog, if `-delete` doesn't work use `-exec rm -f {} +` instead.

Comment: Can you get `find` to be verbose as it deletes?  I suppose the "globstar" method would do this by adding the `-v` switch.

Comment: Demis - yes. if you include `-print` at the end, it will tell you what files it deleted. For example `find . -type f -name ".Apple*" -delete -print`

Comment: `rm -rf **/.DS_Store` is really the one every Apple user wants

Answer (score 29):

I ran into problems using `find` with `-delete` due to the intentional behavior of `find` (i.e. refusing to delete if the path starts with ./, which they do in my case) as stated in its man page:

> ```
>  -delete
> ```
>
> Delete found files and/or directories.  Always returns true. This executes from the current working directory as find recurses down the tree.  It will not attempt to delete a filename with a "/" character in its pathname relative to "." for security reasons.
>   Depth-first traversal processing is implied by this option.
>   Following symlinks is incompatible with this option.

Instead, I was able to just do

```
find . -type d -name 'received_*_output' -exec rm -r {} +
```

For your case, it seems that quoting the glob (asterisk, *) was the solution, but I wanted to provide my answer in case anyone else had the similar problem.

NOTE: Previously, my answer was to do the following, but @Wildcard pointed out the security flaws in doing that in the comments.

```
find . -type d -name 'received_*_output' | xargs rm -r
```

Comment: No good reason to use `xargs` here.  `-exec rm -r {} \;` or, better, `-exec rm -r {} +` will do as well without failing on special character filenames.  See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Comment: That's good to know. Not worth a downvote, IMO, since the command still gets the job done, but the performance optimization is appreciated.

Comment: If it were just a performance optimization I would agree with you, but it's not.    It's a security hole.  You're not correctly handling files with whitespace in their names, and a maliciously crafted filename will result in data loss.  Also see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/135943); *some* of that is applicable and it may at least give you some idea of the *type* of issues I'm talking about.

Comment: Try `mkdir -p $'blah\nDocuments\n/etc\n/home\n/received__output'` in your directory and then run the same command again, if you don't believe there's potential for data loss.  Or, since the question is about Mac OS, `mkdir -p $'blah\nDocuments\n/Users\n/Applications\n/received__output'`.  (**Warning:** You WILL delete all your files if you do this.  That's kind of my point.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
shopt -s dotglob           # using Bash
printf '%s\n' ./.Apple*    # test
#rm -rf ./.Apple*
```

Comment: `dotglob` is useless here. See [this page](http://halisway.blogspot.com/2007/02/bash-globbing-and-dot-files.html) for an example of what dotglob does.

Answer (score -1):

What is possible is that there is nothing wrong with your rm/find command, but that the user you are logged in with doesn't actually have delete permissions. Use `ls -l` to list things with their permissions, and you can identify who you are with the `id` and `groups` commands (either should be available). If you are the "wrong user" to do this, you would need to either change the permissions/ownership of the files, or switch to another user.

Answer (score -3):

Simple command:

```
rm `find ./ -name '.Apple*'` -rf
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is extremely error-prone, find has -exec key.