# Zipping all sub directories

Tags: find, zip

Trying to zip a backup directories inside a parent directory `data/` which looks like this

```
data
|- 2019-04-01
    |- data.gz
    |- data2.gz
|- 2019-04-09
    |- data.gz
    |- data2.gz
```

I would like to zip the timestamped directories in same named zips and delete the unzipped directories

```
data
|- 2019-04-01.zip
|- 2019-04-09.zip
```

I have tried this find command to zip them but I'm having a no such file error
`find . -type d -execdir zip -r {}.zip {} ';'` What am I doing wrong on this command?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the command you mentioned. However, this looks like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/delete-files-and-directories-by-their-names-no-such-file-or-directory/115869#115869

You should do the `-execdir` and then do `-delete`, note that `-execdir` is probably useless, use `-exec` instead, since you appear to be in `data/` already ?

Comment: @thecarpy Why you think he is in data dir? `-execdir` is fine here. @spy-killer Your command works, but you should use `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth  2` to not also zip data and `.` folders.

Comment: I think he is in data because he mentions "parent directory" `data/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your command works fine, but it also zips `data` and `.` directory.
Use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options.

To delete the directories afterwards, use `-execdir rm -Rf {} +`:

```
find data -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -execdir zip -r {}.zip {} \; -execdir rm -Rf {} +
```

Comment: Op should probably use `-delete` iso `-execdir rm...` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/find-exec-rm-vs-delete imho ;-)

Comment: afaik `find -delete` does not work on non-empty folders.

Comment: true, true, learned something new again today ;-)