# Recursively remove certain folder from entire folder tree

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, filesystems, find

Given a directory `projects/` whose subfolders may have a `venv/` folder at variable depths

```py
projects/foo/src/venv/     # venv/ at depth 2
projects/bar/venv/         # venv/ at depth 1
projects/baz/src/core/venv # venv/ at depth 3
projects/woo/              # venv/ non-existent
```

How can I recursively search and delete any `venv/` folders that exist at any depth within `projects/` and it's subfolders?

I've tried

```bash
~/projects $ find . -name venv -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

but receive the error

```bash
find: ‘./foo/venv’: No such file or directory
```

It seems to only search the most immediate subfolder, and because `venv/` is inside of `foo/src/` rather than simply `foo/`, it fails.

I need a command that will do an exhaustive recursive search throughout the entire folder tree.

Comment: Use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115869/414186)

Comment: Adding `-depth` to the command was an easy fix. I unfortunately can't submit that as an answer now though, given that the mods closed this as a duplicate.