# find -delete does not delete non-empty directories

Tags: find, osx

The command

```
$ find ~ -name .DS_Store -ls -delete
```

works on Mac OS X, but

```
$ find ~ -name __pycache__ -type d -ls -delete
```

does not - the directories are found but not deleted.

**Why?**

**PS.** I know I can do

```
$ find ~ -name __pycache__ -type d -ls -exec rm -rv {} +
```

the question is **why** `find -delete` does **not** work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`find`'s `-delete` flag works similar to [`rmdir`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/rmdir.1.html) when deleting directories. If the directory isn't empty when it's reached it can't be deleted.

You need to empty the directory first. Since you are specifying `-type d`, `find` won't do that for you.

You can solve this by doing two passes: first delete everything within dirs named `__pycache__`, then delete all dirs named `__pycache__`:

```
find ~ -path '*/__pycache__/*' -delete
find ~ -type d -name '__pycache__' -empty -delete
```

Somewhat less tightly controlled, but in a single line:

```
find ~ -path '*/__pycache__*' -delete
```

This will delete anything within your home that has `__pycache__` as part of its path.

Comment: On find 4.4.2, that last command needs to be `find ~ -path '*/__pycache__*' -delete`, or probably `find ~ -path '*/__pycache__/*' -o -name __pycache__ -delete` to be safe.

Comment: @naught101, that should be `find ~ \( -path '*/__pycache__/*' -o -name __pycache__ \) -delete` as _and_ has precedence over _or_.

Comment: isn't there a force flag for find, so that it also deletes non-empty directories?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple potential reasons for this.

**1)** 
You told it to delete directories only (`-type d`), and those directories still have files inside them.

**2)** 
Your directories only contain other directories, so the `-type d` will take care of the contents issue. However you are using OS-X, which is largely based on FreeBSD, and the FreeBSD `find` by default will process the directory before its contents.
However the `-depth` option exists to solve this problem by telling `find` to process the directory after its contents.

```
find ~ -name __pycache__ -type d -ls -delete -depth
```

This issue does not exist on linux because the `-delete` option implicitly enables `-depth`.

FreeBSD `man 1 find`:

> ```
>  -depth  Always true; same as the non-portable -d option. Cause find to
>    perform a depth-first traversal, i.e., directories are visited in
>    post-order and all entries in a directory will be acted on before
>    the directory itself. By default, find visits directories in
>    pre-order, i.e., before their contents. Note, the default is not
>    a breadth-first traversal.
> ```

GNU `man 1 find`:

> ```
>  -depth Process each directory's contents before the directory itself. The -delete
>         action also implies -depth.
> ```

Comment: Yeah, but [FreeBSD’s find(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find(1)) says for **`-delete`**, “… Depth-first traversal processing is implied by this option.”, and [GNU find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) says, “… **-delete** implies **-depth**, …”, so it shouldn’t be necessary to add **`-depth`** to the command.

Comment: From the GNU `find` manpage: _"To prevent confusion, global options should specified on the command-line after the list of start points,  just  before  the  first  test,  positional   option or action. If you specify a global option in some other place, find will issue a warning message explaining that this can be confusing."_ Now, `-delete` is a "global option" after the `~` in the command given. I have also noticed that it makes no difference whether you add `-depth` or not. Nonempty directories stay undeleted (but that's probably because I use `-maxdepth` too)

Comment: Even with `-depth`, `-delete` can't delete non-empty directories.