# Moving files to directories named after the first 6 digits in the file name

Tags: files, mkdir, move, qnap

I've got thousands of raw photos (`.nef`) and relative settings (same  filename but `.xmp` extension) in a single directory on a QNAP nas. My goal is to automate the creation of subdirs named like `yyyy-mm` or else `yyyy/mm` and moving there all files accordingly.
All file names are like `yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss-###.nef` or `yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss-###.xmp` where `###` are milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the years that these files' names span, you could just brute-force it:

```
for year in {1996..2018}; do
    for month in {01..12}; do
        mkdir -p ${year}-${month}
        for filetype in nef xmp; do
            mv ${year}-${month}*.${filetype} ${year}-${month}/
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Quoting the asterisk makes this not work (and quoting the rest is useless here)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop based solution with the restricted command set available on a standard QNAP:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ????-??-??_*.{nef,xmp}
do
    yyyymm=${file/-??_*}
    echo mkdir -p "$yyyymm"
    echo mv -f "$file" "$yyyymm/"
done
```

Put this into a file such as `/root/fixup`, change to the directory containing your many files, and run `bash /root/fixup`. It will create the `yyyy-mm` directories on demand, based on the filenames it's processing.

*As written, it will make no changes.* When you are happy that it looks like it's going to work, remove the word `echo` from the two lines near the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simply mass create directories following a pattern you can use:

```
mkdir -p ~/{0001,0002,0003,...,XXXX}/{01,02,03,...,XX}
```

Make sure you substitute the variables with values you actually want to use so an example to create a sub-directory for years, months, and days would look like this:

```
mkdir -p ~/{1998..2018}/{Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}/{01..31}
```

Then you can search through the months that do not have 31 days and remove them as described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89929/276845). After that you have the task of sorting the photos into the proper directories. This is done very similar to finding and deleting and is described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154819/276845).

Please note that this will create the sub-directories in your current working directory. As mentioned by user DopeGhoti, you can create a for loop to complete each step at once. Best of Luck!